# Проблема понимания ассемблера

Tags: ассемблер

Начал изучать ассемблер и не могу просто его понять. Как мне сделать на операционной системе windows 8 64 бита просто привет мир и скомпилировать это в exe файл?
Видел tasm,masm,fasm и другие. Но так ничего толком и не понял. Подскажите как стартануть

Comment: Начинать изучение ассемблера с работы в современных операционных системах и на современном железе очень сложно. Лучше начать с эмуляторов 8086 в реальном режиме. И только освоим в должной мере основы, начинать использовать полноценные компиляторы и разрабатывать полноценные программы.

Comment: а где все это можно скачать.развернуть,читать об этом?

Comment: google://"Питер Абель ассемблер pdf". Имейте в виду, что вы будете понимать _принципы_. Для понимания работы в других операционных системах потребуется дополнительное чтение и практика.

Comment: Большое спасибо. буду изучать

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php

Comment: Вот не соглашусь, что проще начинать с 8086 в реальном режиме (т.е. фактически с DOS). Это традиция, оставшаяся, собственно, со времен DOS. Плюсы изучения под Windows - плоская модель памяти (вместо сегментированной), человекочитаемые имена функций WinAPI (вместо номеров прерываний и номеров функций), не нужен эмулятор, можно сразу использовать современные средства разработки (трансляторы, редакторы, отладчики, дизассемблеры).